# Sharing classes between applications

Tags: c#

I'm working on a Visual Studio solution that currently has two projects in it (with more to come later). One project is a mature C#/Winforms application that I built last year (think of it as the prototype). The other one is a DLL that is going to do the same thing as the prototype but through a different application. I'd like to re-use code from the prototype (let's call the method in question *SyncInvoices()* ) in the DLL because the prototype code works perfectly b/c I've hammered the bugs out of it. The class that contains SyncInvoices is baked into the prototype application instead of being its own DLL.

I've added the class that contains SyncInvoices() to the DLL's project (as a linked file, since it already exists elsewhere in the solution). I can instantiate that class in the DLL project and call SyncInvoices() but the compiler throws errors related to GUI elements.

The problem is  that SyncInvoices() has some-thread safe calls to the Prototype application's GUI  in it, basically used to pass messages/errors back to the interface.

The DLL doesn't have a GUI, so it doesn't need to run that code. It still builds the rest of the methods in that class, even though they aren't used. Is there a way I can tell the compiler to ignore those lines when building the DLL? I'd rather not maintain two sets of nearly identical code, especially when the two projects are part of the same solution.

I thought about using #define/ #if blocks to partition off the code but I'm not sure if C# works that way-- most of the time I've seen those used is to keep debug code from ending up in production. If it is possible to tell the app to include/exclude code through #if blocks, how do I set the values?

Should I just bite the bullet and make a copy of the method without the offending code in it?

Comment: Ya...you comment the code out I guess? Some code would help...

Comment: What you need to do is to separate the common code into it's own project/dll (without the gui stuff) and then reference it to both of your projects needing the functionality.

Comment: Sounds to me like you have violated separation of concerns and it is now biting you. Do the separation now.

Comment: Reference a DLL containing the shared functionality in another DLL that is meant to be a standalone? The reason why the app was built the way it is is at the time there were no plans to re-implement the code. All that came later after the prototype had been in use for awhile. The prototype's biggest flaw is that it  wasn't designed to be automated, so this DLL is going to run in our in-house scheduling app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without more specifics it's hard to give the *correct* answer, but I'd say generally you'd handle this with events.  Whatever calls into the GUI are happening in the prototype, that would typically be some form of event, which you would subscribe to in the prototype when you instantiate your new class.

Are there any particularly problematic cases you could give more specifics on?

Comment: Basically, the GUI calls are fairly minor. There is one method that disables/enables certain widgets during a job, while another writes output to a ListBox I'm using as an output area, while another writes to the system log. The DLL project can run silently (without output) unless it encounters a problem and needs to send output back to its parent app. I suppose all that can be handled with events.

Comment: Sounds like an ideal use case for the disable/enable/updates.  On the output, an event can certainly work, but you might want to consider something like [Task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh195051%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if it's really the primary output or a logical operation (as opposed to an occasional event/etc).  Good luck out there!